# R: Trying to replace strings in data frame based one conditional(s), getting missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, conditional-statements

The overall goal is the rewrite a table of strings (contents of composite samples in a experiment) with a new string representing what is the majority element (M, L, or B). I've used stri_count_fixed to get counts of each element and have these counts in three separate vectors, MO, LI, and BA.  Now I want to rewrite the original string as either M, L or B based on which number is the greatest, and if there is a tie, replace the string with "T".  Note: there is one NA.

So my for loop is:

```
for (i in 1:60) {
  if (is.nan(MO[i])) {content$Content[i]<-NA)
    } else {    
      if (MO[i] > LI[i] && MO[x] > BA[i]){
        content$Content[x]<-"M"
      } else {
        if (LI[i] > MO[i] && LI[i] > BA[i]) {
          content$Content[i]<-"L"
        } else {
          if (BA [i] > MO[i] && BA[i] > LI[i]) {
            content$Content[i]<-"B"
          } else {
            content$Content[i]<-"T"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I understand that this error means that either MO[i], LI[i], or BA[i] are throwing NA, though I don't understand how this can happen for simple vectors. If I replace all the i's with 1's, the if chain works fine, so I really have no idea what's happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps there is a way to do this without conditionals.  Though in the time I've spent working on this, I could have just done it by hand...

Comment: Note that `is.nan(NA)` is `FALSE`; maybe you want `is.na()` instead??

Comment: Why is it MO[x] and Content[x] in the second if?

Comment: Good catch, ARobertson! That might have been the problem, though I honestly remember just using a different computer and it working. Thanks regardless!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
content$Content = ifelse(is.na(MO), NA,
    ifelse(MO > LI & MO > BA, M,
    ifelse(LI > MO & LI > BA, L,
    ifelse(BI > MO & BA > LI, B, T      )   )   )  )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like data.frames and apply:

```
# recreate data
MO <- round(runif(60,0,10))
MO[c(4,6,10)] <- NA
LI <- round(runif(60,0,10))
BA <- round(runif(60,0,10))

# combine into dataframe
df <- data.frame(MO,LI,BA)

# run function on each row
df$maxes <- apply(df,1,function(x){
  # get the matching letters (could be multiple)
  maxes <- c('M','L','B')[x == max(x)]
  # check for NA, tie, or just send result
  if(any(is.na(maxes))){
    NA
  }else if(length(maxes) > 1){
    'T'
  }else{
    maxes
  }
})
# the character vector
content$Content <- df$maxes
```

Of course, you can skip the maxes variable, but it's nice to double check the answer.